# Signature Error in Gear S3 after OS upgrade from Tizen 2.3.2.3 to Tizen 3.0.0.1

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables, tizen-studio

My Gear S3 was running on Tizen 2.3.2.3. Yesterday, I updated it to Tizen 3.0.0.1. Now, when I am trying to install app from Tizen Studio 1.2, it shows following error

"The application installation on the device has failed due to a signature error! (error code: -12)"

[image]

Previously it worked with a certificate I generated with my device's DUID. But, its not working now. I have created new Certificates(both public and partner level), but still its showing same error for both certificate profiles.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update Tizen Studio version to 2.0 and apply light reset to your gear device. After completing reset, connect it with gear manager to start the device and set date & time of gear device exactly to the date & time of your development PC.

If still the problem exists, delete old certificates and create new one.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was solved by creation of SAMSUNG certs. This possibility appears in Certificate Manager after installing package "Extension SDK->IOT-Headless->Samsung Certificate Extension" in Package Manager. My Tizen studio version is 2.1.

When the extension is installed, just follow the instruction: http://developer.samsung.com/z/develop/getting-certificates/create

This allows you not only to generate new DUIDs, but to add the existing ones.

Hope, it will help. As for Tizen certs, it looks, Gear S3 with Tizen 3.0 doesn't recognize it as valid at all.