# the application installation on the device has failed due to a signature error - tizen studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-studio

I'm building an app for my gear s3 frontier using Tizen Studio. However there's a signature error every time I try to run the app on my device. I tried pretty much everything(creating certificates, setting the same date/hour on my PC and wear) but the problem persists. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Clean your project and run again ..... if still exists, restart your IDE

Comment: hey thanks for your response! i did that but still the problem is not solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use latest version of [Tizen Studio](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download). At first light reset your device. 
To light reset your device go to

***Settings > About Gear > Reset Gear***

After resetting, pair your Gear with your phone using [Samsung Gear Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.app.watchmanager&hl=en_IN) app. Set the time and date of your Gear by following the date and time of the development machine.

Then try again to install your project to gear from Tizen Studio.

If the problem still exists, delete your old certificates from both **Certificate Manager** and **File explorer** (/home/User/SamsungCertificate).

Again create certificate and try!

Also you may follow these threads

[Signature Error in Gear S3 after OS upgrade from Tizen 2.3.2.3 to Tizen 3.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614917/signature-error-in-gear-s3-after-os-upgrade-from-tizen-2-3-2-3-to-tizen-3-0-0-1)

[Tizen app not installing on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994548/tizen-app-not-installing-on-device)

Comment: Did you need to re-create the certificate? or just resetting did the job ?

Answer (score 4):

To install your application on a Samsung device it needs to be signed with a Samsung certificate profile, not a Tizen certificate profile. In a default install the Tizen Studio certificate manager only creates Tizen certificate profiles. This was the problem in my case.

To enable creating a Samsung certificate profile, start the package manager (in Tizen studio: Tools -> Package manager), go to the 'Extension SDK' tab, expand 'Extras' and install 'Samsung Certificate Extension'.

After installing this, use the Certificate Manager (in Tizen studio: Tools -> Certificate manager) and create a new certificate profile (possibly first delete your existing certificate if you didn't publish anything). Now it'll let you choose between creating a Tizen certificate profile and a Samsung certificate profile. You'll need to sign in to a Samsung account to be able to create a Samsung certificate profile. Make sure that the Samsung certificate profile is the active one when you're done.

Comment: Tagging related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994548/tizen-app-not-installing-on-device